# Yii: Change login page

Tags: php, authentication, yii, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

When we create a yii webapp using yiic, a login function is already made.
However, I want to use the navbar as a login widget (and bootstrap for design) as shown in [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/564p51fytzk28rc/After%20submit.jpg). That's when I encountered my problem. When I try to login using the toolbar/widget, the details I have input are displayed in the browser's bar and then nothing. See [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2sn0vm3xbrr9lho/Navigation.jpg).

This my LoginWidget.php

```
<?php class LoginWidget extends CWidget {
public function run() {
    $model=new LoginForm;

    $form= $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'login-form',
        // 'action'=>
        'enableClientValidation'=>true,
        'clientOptions'=>array(
            'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
            )
        ));

    echo $form->errorSummary($model);
    ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'username',array('placeholder'=>'Employee Code','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'username'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('placeholder'=>'Password','class'=>'form-control')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    echo CHtml::submitButton('Sign in', array('class'=>'btn btn-success'));
    $this->endWidget();
}
```

} ?>

This is my Controller (just the necessary part).

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect('myprofile/index');
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));

    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    // $this->render('index');
}
```

When I try to login using localhost/project/index.php/site/login, it works.

Comment: Your dropbox links don't work.

Comment: Sorry, it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the form sends data with POST

```
$form= $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'login-form',
    'method' => 'POST',
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>
       array(
        'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
       )
));
```